# c# draw many circle at the same time

Tags: c#, charts

I tried to build my own *Polar Chart*. I use a function to draw points as follows:

```
private void drawPoints()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (Point Pointaktuell in PointList)
    {
        int radius = 15;

        Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

        g.FillEllipse(b, (int)(Pointaktuell.X - radius / 2.0), (int)(Pointaktuell.Y - radius / 2.0), radius, radius);
        i++;
    }
    PointList.Clear();
    this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

The problem is that the *points* are draw one after one, and need a lot of time. How can I draw them all at once?

Comment: First note: Delete "Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);" and "int radius = 15;" in the foreach loop and create them outside the loop.

Comment: Your instantiating a new instance of `SolidBrush` in each loop step. And you are redefining `radius` every time again and again. Why not take those out of the loop like; `const int radius = 15;` and `Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)` and why use `foreach` if you are going to need a counter `i` ? why not `for`

Comment: It will only be noticeably slow when you draw thousands of circles. Inevitably you'll overlap points, making them disappear.  So you're wasting time drawing points that the user can never see.  Another significant problem is you using CreateGraphics().  That's always wrong, you must use the Paint event.  Which supports double-buffering, making it a lot less obvious that these points are drawn one-by-one.  Double-buffering yourself in a bitmap so you don't have to do this repeatedly is another standard trick, now it is a very cheap DrawImage() call.  Or use the Chart control.

Comment: _Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();_ Dead on arrival! This will never persist.

Answer (score 2):

To *optimize* the drawing procedure, try put as more code as you can *outside* the loop. Do not forget to close `IDisposable`

```
private void drawPoints() 
{
    SuspendLayout();

    try 
    {
        using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics()) 
        {
            int i = 0; 
            int radius = 15;

            using (b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)) 
            {
                foreach (Point Pointaktuell in PointList) 
                {
                    g.FillEllipse(b, (int)(Pointaktuell.X - radius / 2.0), (int)(Pointaktuell.Y - radius / 2.0), radius, radius);
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
        }
   }
   finally { ResumeLayout(); }
}
```

Comment: Why try catch if *optimization* is in question? I suppose only the method `FillEllipse` might throw an `ArgumentNullException` if `SolidBrush` parameter is `null`. Which in case *can not* be

Comment: "finally" is very cheap (in contrast with "catch"); whenever you acquire resource, set a lock, suspend (e.g. SuspendLayout) you have to free, reset, resume (ResumeLayout).

Answer (score 0):

A new `SolidBrush` instantiated in each loop step. And `radius` is redefined every time again and again. `Dispose()` routine is not called for Instantiated objects (which comes to be important for `Graphics`)

You might try the following;

```
private void drawPoints()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();

    const int radius = 15;
    using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        //if (g == null) { this.ResumeLayout(); return; } // # Uncomment this line if you want defensive checks
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PointList.Count; i++)
            {
                g.FillEllipse(b, (int)(PointList[i].X - radius / 2.0), (int)(PointList[i].Y - radius / 2.0), radius, radius);
            }
        }
    }

    PointList.Clear();
    this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

This is only if you'r going to do all drawing stuff in `drawPoints()` and call it once in a time. If you'r going to call `drawPoints()` periodically or have more drawing routines in other parts of the flow; i suggest you keep that `Graphics g` and `Brush b` referances globally and `Dispose()` when they are no longer needed (no more drawing in this case)